# Personalizar diseño de menu de NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout

Necesito poder personalizar el menu de un `NavigationView`, por ejemplo el que trae por defecto el `Android Studio` 1.4

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_cuenta" android:actionLayout="@layout/boton_face" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
        android:title="Mis Datos" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_set_as"
        android:title="Salir" />
</group>
```

Seria lograr que cada item pueda poner otro icono por ejemplo a la derecha, o poder ponerle un fondo.

Comment: Prueba con el atributo `app:actionLayout` y comprueba esto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560663/navigationview-menu-items-with-counter-on-the-right.  Lo que necesitas es algo parecido.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que estas buscando? Así sabriamos mejor como contestarte. El `Navigation View` se puede personalizar de muchas formas y seria una pregunta con una contestación muy amplia. ¿Y donde quieres poner un fondo?

Comment: Puedes aportar un ejemplo gráfico para entender más bien como quieres que quede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deseas personalizar tu `Navigation Drawer` agregando un icono y un fondo:

Puedes crear una vista ImageView que contenga el icono y el color, por ejemplo `icono_derecha.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

Esta vista la puedes cargar desde los elementos que conforman tu `Navigation Drawer`, por medio de la propiedad **`app:actionLayout`** que define el nombre de la vista a cargar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Importar"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/icono_derecha"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Galería"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/icono_derecha"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/icono_derecha"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Herramientas"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/icono_derecha"/>
    </group>    

</menu>
```

para obtener :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para cambiar el color del background puedes usar la propiedad **`app:itemBackground`** donde podemos definir un color o un drawable :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:title="Galería"
    app:itemBackground="@color/color_red"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir un icono a la derecha, para notificar algo etc...

Añadir `app:actionLayout` en los items de los menus

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
...
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_right_image" />
...
```

crear el layout donde contendrá la imagen de la derecha `menu_right_image.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
```

Personalización al completo, para el menú lateral:
http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/
 o ese tutorial http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/