# Actualizar un contador dentro del NavigationView (menú lateral) en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un `NavigationView` con un elemento donde hay un contador a su derecha, para indicar cuantos elementos hay para ver.

En [Personalizar diseño de menu de NavigationView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12978/personalizar-dise%C3%B1o-de-menu-de-navigationview) he seguido los paso para agregar un contador mas o menos como la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
```

Para modificar su contenido uso setText

```
TextView myCounter = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.my_counter);
if (myCounter != null) {
    myCounter.setText("99+");
}
```

Si lo pongo dentro de un evento `onClick` de un botón, se modifica el valor de `0` a `99+`

Pero no consigo modificarlo cuando se inicia la aplicación, lo he probado en `onCreate() y onStart()`

He buscado por SO y algunas soluciones es usar un `runnable`, pero no creo que sea lo más adecuado esperar que el menú este cargado del todo para modificar el valor del contador.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que necesitas exactamente, que cuando se pulse un botón se incremente o que automáticamente la app detecte que hay nuevos items a mostrar?

Comment: que la app cuando se lance, actualice el contador, es decir en onCreate no consigo modificar su valor

Comment: A mi me ha pasado lo mismo con mis aplicaciones tuve una gran pelea para modificar el menú lateral,,al parecer modificar elementos estáticos crea muchos problemas,  al final lo que hice fue hacer un xml aparte para el diseño del drawer lateral, con eso ya tienes total control sobre todos los elementos como si se tratara de un xml mas. Dime si quieres que te ponga un ejemplo, un saludo.

Comment: Ya lo he encontrado, ha costado

Comment: En vez de usar onCreate podrías intentar con onPostCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar el valor del contador dinamicamente cuando se lance la `activity` se debe hacer en el evento donde se prepara los items de los menús, `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    TextView myCounter = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.my_counter);
    if (myCounter != null) {
        myCounter.setText("99+");
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Me gusta esta respuesta, pero también he visto otro tipo de construcción de los elementos del navigation Drawer, se crean dentro de un listview o un ExpandableListView que esta agregado al menú, eso sería otra situación.

Comment: Buenas, algunos ejemplos que he ojeado usan a menudo un setAdapter sobre el DrawerMenu y después me temo que  es 100% personalizable, supongo que para cambiar el contador se podría realizar dentro del adapter.

Comment: Exacto! yo regularmente lo uso así! :)